# fetch response always sends index.html content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-build

I've created a react app with a node backend.
I'm trying to build it in order to deploy it on Netlify, but when I'm trying to `npm run build` on the root folder on my terminal, I get this error:

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: C:\Users\user\Desktop\stock-manager\public
```

I created this app using the `npm create-react-app` command but it seems like it didn't create a public folder in my root folder.
my root folder looks like this:

```
> client
> node_modules
> server
{} package-lock.json
{} package.json
```

On my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build":"react-scripts build"
  },
```

***Edit***
I managed to run the build command and it worked out, now I'm facing another problem: when deployed, all fetch requests responses return the content of the index.html file instead of what's really meant to be in the response.

Any idea on what could be the solution?

Comment: do you have index.html in your public folder?

Comment: Do you mean the public folder which is in my client folder?

Comment: yes, if you try to upload to netlify the client also.

Comment: I still can't build it properly.. am I supposed to run the build command on my client folder or on the root folder?

Comment: yes, 
just check if you have index.html in your public folder after you run the build script.

Comment: Yes I do have it. I ran the build command through the client directory on the terminal and it worked, but now when i deploy the app it wont navigate through pages properly (react navigate doesnt work)